# How to run and test AngularJS project in IntellijIDEA?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, intellij-idea, karma-runner

I created AngularJS project in IntellijIDEA. And I didn't find any information how to run and test it with Karma framework. Also I installed NodeJS and plugins for AngularJS to Karma and Jasmine. How to correctly run it and test? 
Here is my project structure. I use first Angular.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the `karma.conf.js` file, choose '**Create "karma.conf.js"**' - this action will create Karma run configuration; then run the created configuration.
See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/02/your-first-unit-test-using-angular-cli-karma-and-webstorm/ - you might find this article helpful